# C++ Setting the Date for localtime

Tags: c++, unit-testing, datetime

I have a piece of C++ code in C++11 that uses `localtime` function ([doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)) to get the time. If the day is my birthday, it returns a birthday message.

```
std::string message = getDailyMessage();
```

I would now like to make a unit test that determines if the code outputs the right value on my birthday and not on my birthday. Is there a way to programmatically set the value returned by `localtime` before two adjacent calls? Is it possible to do without mucking around with the actual system time?

```
setTime(NOT_BIRTHDAY);
EXPECT_STREQ(NOT_BIRTHDAY_MESSAGE, getDailyMessage());
setTime(BIRTHDAY);
EXPECT_STREQ(BIRTDAY_MESSAGE, getDailyMessage());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `getDailyMessage` take the time by parameter. This makes unit testing a breeze and adds the flexibility of being able to use it in other contexts. For instance you could use it to print the yesterday's message.

Comment: This is a great suggestion in general; unfortunately the setup here is simplified and the structure of the actual system is such that the functionality being testing requires a `localtime` call buried inside it.

Comment: @Steve • that's tightly binding two things tightly together.  Makes for highly difficult unit testing.  Separate them, and it will be much easier to unit test.

Comment: @Eljay I agree, but the structure is set for me so the test must be as it is.

Comment: So the answers are:  _Is there a way to programmatically set the value returned by localtime before two adjacent calls?_  Yes, set the actual system time.  _Is it possible to do without mucking around with the actual system time?_  Without extricating the localtime from the implementation, no.